# How to make a brochure from a pdf file in ubuntu?

Tags: python, printing, libreoffice, pdf

Say that I have a 16-page pdf file, A4 sized. I have A4 paper and printer. I want to shrink it to halves, and print them on 4 sheets of paper, double side, fold them in halves, and staple it in the middle.
The way I do it now is to export it to PNG, use LibreOffice Writer to rearrange them. This is time-consuming. Is there a better way to do it? If I have a 64 page file.
PS: What if this is a dictionary and I shall Coptic bind it? https://www.wikihow.com/Coptic-Bind-a-Book  How to create folios?
My (theoretically，not implemented) solution is to write a Python Script.

Comment: That DTP process you are talking about is called `imposition`. You can find few solution here: [Gluing (Imposition) PDF documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465271/gluing-imposition-pdf-documents) or here: [PDF::Impose](https://github.com/jamis/impose)

Comment: Did you try boomaga virtual printer software? https://www.boomaga.org/ (Available in Ubuntu Software Center.)

Comment: It seemed that the SO question is rather old... Maybe the need arose then.

Comment: Unfortunately I am in a region with limited internet access, and snap store is out of reach.

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR:** the tool for this is called `pdfbook`

You don't need to write anything. The tool already exists, and does what you want (four-page signatures of 2-up duplex-printed pages) by default. Indeed, if you had a 64-page PDF, by default `pdfbook` will arrange the pages such that you will use 16 sheets of paper, and print four separate signatures ready for binding precisely as you describe.

`pdfbook` is provided by `texlive-extra-utils`:

```
sudo apt install -y texlive-extra-utils
pdfbook MY-FANCY-MANUSCRIPT.PDF
```

Outputs a file arranged as you describe called `MY-FANCY-MANUSCRIPT-book.PDF` suitable for immediate printing however you may like.

Comment: It seems simple, but I haven't used TEX before, and 269MB just seemed too much for my old and outdated SSD.

Comment: Thanks anyway, Maybe next time I retire my laptop.

Comment: it works, thanks. In default mode, I had to flip it twice to print in a single side printing printer.

Answer (score 6):

There's a handy tool you can download from Ubuntu Software Center to make booklets called PDF Mix Tool.

[image: PDF Mix Tool in Ubuntu Software Center]

Comment: It should be noted that this is a snap app and it can also be installed by running `sudo snap install pdfmixtool` in a terminal.

Answer (score 5):

The printing system by itself has [brochure-capability](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSPdfToPdf#bonus):

> **A pdftopdf Bonus**
>
> Very simply - try this:
>
> ```
> /usr/sbin/cupsfilter -p test.ppd -m application/vnd.cups-pdf -o 'fit-to-page booklet' mixed.pdf > out.pdf
> ```

`test.ppd` may be replaced by your printer's PPD from `/etc/cups/ppd`. You will need to use `sudo` to get a copy of the PPD.

`cupsfilter` processes any input file, using printing system filters, to produce, as instructed by the `-m` option, `out.pdf`. Actually, the `-p` option can be omitted. One of the processing options (`-o`) is `booklet`, which produces a PDF in booklet format.

It took me less than 30 seconds to convert a 30-pages document to booklet format using the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/cupsfilter -m application/vnd.cups-pdf -o 'fit-to-page booklet' any.pdf > out.pdf
```

Comment: Just a small note: `/usr/sbin/` can be omitted and you can use `cupsfilter` without the full path to it, as `/usr/sbin` should already be in the `PATH` in a default Ubuntu installation.